# What are all the languages supported by Siri as of Apple iOS 7.1? Is there a changelog available?

Tags: applications, siri, ios

I was able to find this information from the official support documentation for Siri: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4992

> Siri understands and can speak the following languages:
>
> - United States (English, Spanish)
> - United Kingdom (English)
> - Australia (English)
> - France (French)
> - Germany (German)
> - Japan (Japanese)
> - Canada (Canadian French, English)
> - China (Mandarin)
> - Hong Kong (Cantonese)
> - Italy (Italian)
> - Korea (Korean)
> - Mexico (Spanish)
> - Spain (Spanish)
> - Switzerland (French, German, Italian)
> - Taiwan (Mandarin)

But I don't think it has been updated as of iOS 7.1 (the page shows Last Modified: Sep 18, 2013). So...

- What are all the languages that Siri supports as of iOS 7.1?
- Is there an changelog available showing languages added in each version right from the beginning?

Comment: For languages evolution see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri#Supported_languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a change log available, you can find it [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1732?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).
This is what it says about siri:

**Siri**

- Manually control when Siri listens by holding down the home button
  while you speak and releasing it when you're done as an alternative
  to letting Siri automatically notice when you stop talking
- New, more natural sounding male and female voices for Mandarin
  Chinese, UK English, Australian English, and Japanese

And the change log you mentioned isn't updated because there was no need for it, I verified on my iPhone running iOS 7.1 and there are no new languages in addition to the list you posted.

On the developer portal there is another change log [(here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246) that shows all changes in different versions.
It is a lot more technical than the "consumer log".

Comment: Hello Dennis, in the question, I didn't ask about what's new in iOS 7.1. I asked, "Is there an changelog available **showing languages added in each version right from the beginning?**"

Comment: there isn't a log like that, you could check the developer portal here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246 but This is only information related to the technical changes in different versions

Comment: That's it! **1.** You answered my first question with, *"I verified on my iPhone running iOS 7.1 and there are no new languages in addition to the list you posted."*. **2.** [The link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246) you posted in the comment has links to all major versions of iOS after 4.0 (and Siri became available only in iOS 5). So, please modify your answer to include this info, and I'll be happy to tick it off. Thank you very much!